# Hassio won't connect dhcp

Tags: home-assistant

My home assistant setup died apparently due to a dead SD card so I downloaded the whole image, burned to a new card, and bought an RPi4 to load it up on. It seems to work fine (I can see the HASSIO CLI), but can't connect using DHCP, which is its default. I have changed nothing from the original image. I have confirmation on nmcli that the cable is alive and recognizes the gigabit connection.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what happened, but reviewing the logs on my router, I was able to discern that the device DID obtain a DHCP address, but I overrode that with a fixed IP instead, following instructions on the GitHub page for the CLI.

Comment: Hi Jim, glad to hear you found this out. There's no need to be concerned about any minor editing; anyone here can edit to fix any typos, and it's not meant as any form of offence. If anything, editing bumps your post to the top and gets it more attention, although sometimes it can take a few days for posts to get an answer from someone who can help.